# How can jQuery be used to make all relative paths absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, href

Using jQuery, I am trying to find any `<a href="/folder/whatever.file">link</a>` instances on a page and put http://www.domain.com before /folder.

What would be the easiest, safest way to do this?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Long story short: The page exists, I cannot change its html or backend PHP, and it's calling some elements from a sibling site (namely graphics). It's using the relative paths, and since they're on a different site they're not rendering. I need full paths to the images. It's a temporary solution while we build a porting tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update the href of the anchor tag when it is clicked.

```
$(document).on("click","a:not([href^=http])",function(){
    this.href = "http://domain.com" + this.href;
})
```

or better yet

```
$(document).on("click","a[href^=/specificfolder/]",function(){
    this.href = "http://domain.com" + this.href;
});
```

It would probably be better to make this change on your server using htaccess or similar url rewriting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).prop('href')
  $(this).prop('href',"http://domain.com"+href);
});
```

Comment: Yes but other than `$('a').each()`, jQuery is not necessary. `this.href = "http://domain.com" + this.href;` will do the job.